# Are credit cards (Master Card) widely accepted in Budapest?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, museums, restaurants, budapest

Are credit cards accepted in the museums and restaurants in Budapest?

When used in a restaurant, is there a minimum amount you have to spend in order to pay by credit card?

What about public transport? Can I buy tickets for buses, metro using Mastercard?

Answer (score 5):

In the tourist area most restaurants seem to accept credit cards. Always inquiry before seating, as even if the restaurant has the card logos at the door/in menu, sometime they have "technical difficulties" accepting cards - and they don't post it. Three museums I went to accepted card payments for tickets as well.

Haven't seen any posts there about required minimum spending amounts.

Regarding public transport, my knowledge is limited to a few bus stations so I can't speak for all Budapest. At airport you can indeed purchase a bus ticket from a machine using a card (you might need one with a PIN). This is also possible at some central stations. Drivers in buses didn't seem to accept cards.

I did manage to spend two days in Budapest without withdrawing any forints, if this could be of any help.

Answer (score 5):

In Budapest, you can pay by card almost anywhere except the tinyest shops, and in most cases, you can do it contactless.

In tourist areas, some shops take only cash and try to profit from ridiculous conversion rates if you pay by €. There are some tourist-focused restaurants too that don't accept cards (IMHO a bit suspicious), as George said, look for signs or logos on/near the entrance. Museums should be fine.

Having a minimum amount for card payment is [not allowed](https://forbes.hu/penz/nem-lehet-kartyaval-fizetni-mert-tul-kicsi-az-osszeg-pedig-ez-tilos/), but a few places still do it, usually with a relatively low limit (e.g. 1000 HUF).

As for public transport: you can buy tickets/passes by card at [customer service points](http://www.bkk.hu/en/main-page/contact/) and [vending machines](http://bkk.hu/automata/?l=en). Note that while it is officially possible to buy tickets on trams and buses from the driver, it's by cash only and they really don't like it when you try (takes time, they have no change etc.) so try buy them in advance.

(*source: I live in Budapest*)